# Headless Xubuntu server does not recognize usb devices

Tags: server, usb, xubuntu, headless

So I am running Xubuntu 16.04 on a home server, in headless mode. When I start the server with a monitor attached, I can attach usb drives normally and access them. When the server is running headless however (ie it booted up without a monitor attached), it never seems to recognize usb devices being plugged in. Not only do memory sticks not automount, they dont appear in the output of df -h, which makes it impossible to mount the drive manually. Any suggestions on how I can get the server to start headless while still recognizing when a usb device is plugged in?